# "Path does not exist" error using CurrentProject.Path as default folder in FileDialog

Tags: ms-access, vba

So I have written (borrowed as well) some code to automate an export, below is the folderpicker dialoge I am using, curiously by using currentproject.path it starts in the right initial directory, but says the path does not exists until you navigate out and then back into the folder.  I assume this has something to do with the picker not returning a value until you navigate somewhere or something?

This is only an issue because I want the user to be able to specify where they want to save their exports, that includes the current path of the project.  Any ideas?

```
Function GetFolder(Optional startFolder As Variant = -1) As Variant
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim vItem As Variant
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
            If startFolder = -1 Then
           .InitialFileName = CurrentProject.Path
        Else
            If Right(startFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
                .InitialFileName = startFolder & "\"
            Else
                .InitialFileName = startFolder
            End If
        End If
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        vItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

NextCode:
    GetFolder = vItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
    Debug.Print GetFolder
End Function
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a \ to the default folder, and it will not be highlighted.

eg:

```
 .InitialFileName = CurrentProject.Path & "\"
```

Note that they can thus just "hit" ok.

Comment: So simple, so effective.  Thanks you two.